# Using For-loops through an HTML file that was saved as a list of combinations

Tags: python, for-loop, coordinates, combinations

I've saved a list of combinations into HTML file as a list and I want it to act like a list when using in for loop.

the html file was created with this code:

```
xrange = "01"
list1 = []
for x1 in xrange:
    for x2 in xrange:
        for x3 in xrange:
            guess = x1 + x2 + x3
            list1.append(guess)
with open("output2.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(list1))
```

when I try to use For-loop through the HTML file like this:

```
with open('output2.html', 'r') as ht:
    for x in ht:
        print(x)
```

**instead of** (which is what I want)

```
000
001
010
011
100
```

I get this result, output:  (not good)

```
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

please help.
how can I use For Loop to Iterate over this HTML list ?
like this:

```
000
001
010
011
100
```

ps - btw I use HTML file after I've tried pickle and few other ideas, so far html seem to be the fastest for me for big files.

**EDIT:**
I've tried to use Daniel's advise:

```
with open("output2.html", "w") as file: 
    for num in list1: 
    file.write(f'{num}\n')
```

but when I try to run the combinations from the file like this:

```
with open("output2.html", 'r') as f:    
    for x in f:        
        print(x)
```

I get a black line between each combination here is the output:

```
9996

9997

9998

9999
```

Also when I run the main code (which is to guess the password combination), it doesn't notice that the guess = password.

it doesn't get to the line print(f"your password is {guess}")

any idea why ? (it happens only when I use HTML so far)

```
password = "9997"
def html_list_loop():
    htmlist = open('output3.html', 'r')
    for x in htmlist:
        guess = x
        print(guess)
        if password == x:
            print(f"your password is {guess}")
            return
```

thanks a lot for the help.

PS - if you have better and faster way to do that I do like to know how.

Comment: What language does this syntax belong to? Please add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

First, please allow me to explain something about file types.

Adding an `.html` suffix to the file doesn't change or affect the file structure. What you are basically doing is storing that as a textual file. You could call that `.synth` as far as the computer is concerned.

The reason pickle was slower is because that really is a different file format. It's a binary representation of Pythonic objects.

Second, the output you see if simply because you stringify a list (as in, convert a Python list into a string).

If you want to write each value in its own line, you could just replace the last two lines with:

```
with open("output2.html", "w") as file:
  for num in list1:
    file.write(f'{num}\n')
```

There are plenty of ways to make it shorter, cooler, etc. This is basically the most verbose way so that you understand the difference.

UPDATE:

The `print` method adds a new line on top of what already exists in the file.
The solution is simple - Add `.strip` to every line you read:

```
with open("output2.html", 'r') as f:    
    for x in f:
        print(x.strip())
```

And the comparison probably doesn't work for the same reason.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for replying! please check my reply.

Comment: I updated the main post